# How to connect Android Application (java) to Tcp Server(Qt, C++)

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I have a Tcp Server is written on C ++, Qt and I need that be my app on the android could connect to the server to send and read the received data, but I can not understand how to implement it. I tried to use [Qt Jambi](http://qtjambi.org/) but it turned out that this library is not supported android application development, I also tried to be used in my Android application Qt library, in which was connection to the server methods, reading and sending, but the socket is not connected to the server.

> Server.h

```
class Server : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Server(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Server();
    void startServer();
protected:
    void incomingConnection( qintptr handle );
private:
    QThreadPool *pool;
};
```

> Server.cpp

```
Server::Server(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
{
    pool = new QThreadPool(this);
    pool->setMaxThreadCount(5);
}

Server::~Server()
{
    delete pool;
}

void Server::startServer()
{
    if(listen(QHostAddress::Any, 8080)){
        qDebug() << "Server started";
    }else{
        qDebug() << "Server did not start!";
    }
}

void Server::incomingConnection(qintptr handle)
{
    Runnable *runnable = new Runnable();
    runnable->setAutoDelete(true);
    connect(runnable->dataBase, SIGNAL(sendMessageToEmail(QStringList)), this, SLOT(sendMail(QStringList)));
    runnable->socketDescriptor = handle;

    pool->start(runnable);
}
```

> Runnable.cpp

```
    ...
    void Runnable::run()
    {
        if(!socketDescriptor){
            return;
        }

        socket = new QTcpSocket;
        socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);
        QObject::connect(&(*socket), SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconected()));
        outStream << quint16(0);

        while(socket->isOpen())
        {
            socket->waitForReadyRead();
            if(socket->bytesAvailable() == 0){
                continue;
            }
            onReadyRead();
        }
    }

void Runnable::sendToUser()
{
    outStream.device()->seek(0);
    outStream << quint16(arrByteOut.size() - sizeof(quint16));
    socket->write(arrByteOut);
    socket->waitForBytesWritten();
}

void Runnable::onReadyRead()
{
    QDataStream in(socket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);

    if(socket->isOpen())
    {
        if(nextBlockSize == 0){
            in >> nextBlockSize;
        }

        if(socket->bytesAvailable() < nextBlockSize){
            return;
        }

        if(socket->isOpen()){
            queryDefinition(in);
            nextBlockSize = 0;
        }
    }
}
    ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you code so far?? is there a client / server code??

Comment: TSP? Time stamp protocol? Please provide minimal working example of your code. And why did you flag your question with java and c++??

Comment: user16, I use Tcp protocol. I Added the c++ and java flags, becose server is written on c++, android application on java.